# Write/read std::set< T > to/from binary file

Tags: c++, set, std, binaryfiles

I am trying to code a write/read pair of functions with which to respectively store/retrieve a `std::set< T >` data container into/from a binary file. My `writeSet()` function appears to work as desired, and stores `std::set< T >` data containers without any apparent problems. However the `readSet()` function does not, and throws an "Unhandled exception [...] Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEF6." exception AFTER the `main()` function returns `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

As far I can debug (using Visual Studio 2013), `readSet()` does in fact seem to successfully read binary files and correctly allocates data to the addressed `std::set< T >` data container. When VS2013 crashes, it offers me the opporutity to break the program execution, and points me to an error in the xtree.h header file. Specifically the debugger complains about `_Pnext` the line `|| _Ptr != 0 && (*_Pnext)->_Ptr != _Ptr)` of the following section:

```
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    void _Orphan_ptr(_Myt& _Cont, _Nodeptr _Ptr) const
        {   // orphan iterators with specified node pointers
        _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);
        const_iterator **_Pnext = (const_iterator **)_Cont._Getpfirst();
        if (_Pnext != 0)
            while (*_Pnext != 0)
                if ((*_Pnext)->_Ptr == this->_Myhead
                    || _Ptr != 0 && (*_Pnext)->_Ptr != _Ptr)
                    _Pnext = (const_iterator **)(*_Pnext)->_Getpnext();
                else
                    {   // orphan the iterator
                    (*_Pnext)->_Clrcont();
                    *_Pnext = *(const_iterator **)(*_Pnext)->_Getpnext();
                    }
```

My minimal working solution is as follows:

**`writeSet()` : Writes std::set< T > into binary file**

```
template < class T >
void writeSet(const std::string& filePath, const std::string fileName, std::set<T>& data)
{
    // Construct binary file location string using filePath and fileName inputs
    std::stringstream file; file << filePath.c_str() << "/" << fileName.c_str();
    std::ofstream fileStream; fileStream.open(file.str().c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary); 

    // First write number of std::set elements held by data, and then write std::set block to binary file
    std::set<T>::size_type n = data.size(); 
    fileStream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof(std::set<T>::size_type));
    fileStream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(T)*n); 
    fileStream.close();
}
```

**`readSet()` : Reads std::set< T > from binary file**

```
template < class T >
void readSet(const std::string& filePath, const std::string fileName, std::set<T>& data)
{
    // Construct binary file location string using filePath and fileName inputs
    std::stringstream file; file << filePath.c_str() << "/" << fileName.c_str();
    std::ifstream fileStream; fileStream.open(file.str().c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary); 


    // First read number of elements stored in binary file, then write file content to adresses std::set data variable
    std::set<T>::size_type n; 
    fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof(std::set<T>::size_type));
    fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(T)*n); 
    fileStream.close();
}
```

**`main()` : Minimal main function which reproduces the "Unhandled exception" error**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Define binary file read/write directory
    const std::string path("C:/data");

    // writeSet() testing...
    std::set<int> writeSetData;
    writeSetData.insert(1); writeSetData.insert(3);
    writeSetData.insert(0); writeSetData.insert(2);

    writeSet(path, "binaryFile", writeSetData);

    // readSet() testing...
    std::set<int> readSetData;
    readSet(path, "binaryFile", readSetData);

    std::cout << "readSetData= {";
    for (std::set<int>::iterator it = readSetData.begin(); it != readSetData.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << ", ";
    } std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all your `T`s PODs? Otherwise, making a binary copy is just about meaningless, instead of creating a semantic copy.
Also, the data the set managed is saved in dynamically allocated memory managed by the `set`, not in the `set` itself.
As a third point, that space does not magically grow or shrink whenever you try to write an arbitrary amount of elements there.
You have to ask the set to grow by inserting elements manually!

As a side-note, `std::string` works perfectly fine for string concatenations, there's no need to break out the `std::stringstream`!

Comment: This is correct, however I will expand on the answer as it may be hard to understand.  A set class only contains the data and functions necessary to manage data assigned to that class.  It does not contain the assigned data itself.  A set consists of likely a few pointers and integers.  To store the data managed by the set class into a binary file you need to iterate through that container and write the individual entries to a binary file.  To read this data back you need to read these from the binary file and add them individually to the set.

Comment: Thanks Deduplicator and kkurylo; I'd gotten carried away after coding a similar pair of read/write functions for std::vector<T> data container (where the data is stored serially), and forgot that std:set<T> containers are trees... Thanks for the tips!